# CakePHP query record does not show password

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a simple model (User) which contains of the attributes `id`, `username` and `password`.

If I query for records with `$this->User->find()->all()->toArray()`, the output shows the attributes `id` and `username`. Password is not displayed.

No matter if the password is a hash or not, somehow it must be possible to retrieve it only for processing reasons.

Anyone has experienced this issue before?

Comment: What are you using to display the records? As I recall CakePHP's `debug()` method obscures password field values as these shouldn't really be output anywhere regardless of whether you hash them or not. You could try outputting the data using PHP's native `var_dump()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure if its a good thing to want to display a password(hashed of not)

but outputting a user should show it to you.

You can check if there are any hidden properties set with `$entity->hiddenProperties()`

You can pass Either an array of properties to hide or null to get the hidden properties.